# IMU measurement model

Tags: kinematics, imu, accelerometer

I read in this [set of slides](http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/teaching/2016/13_visual_inertial_fusion_advanced.pdf) on p.11 that the IMU measurements, such as acceleration are affected by bias and noise, as expressed in this equation:

$_B \mathbf {\tilde a} _{WB}(t) =\  \mathbf R_{BW}(t)(_W \mathbf a_{WB}(t) -\ _W \mathbf g) + \mathbf b^a(t) + \mathbf n^a(t)$

where $b^a(t)$ is the bias of the accelerometer, $n^a(t)$ is the noise of the accelerometer, ${\tilde a}(t)$ is the measured acceleration, and a(t) is the true acceleration. As for notations:

Left subscript denotes the reference frame in which the quantity is expressed.

Right subscript {Q}{Frame1}{Frame2} denotes Q of Frame2 with respect to Frame1.

Last of all, noises and bias are all in the body frame.

**What I would like to ask is what does the $R$ term in the equation mean and do?** I'm guessing it is a rotation, but why is it needed? Sorry if this question seems trivial, but I'm new to all this and my physics is terrible... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this answer is a bit late, but it could be useful for someone else.

Since the *true* acceleration is defined in the *world frame*, but the IMU's measured acceleration is defined in the *body frame* (the same as the IMU), you need the rotation matrix $_B\mathbf{\tilde{a}}_{WB}(t)$ to convert from one acceleration into the other. If you don't consider this matrix, the calculations will be wrong because you'd be mixing measurements observed from *different perspectives*.

With a practical example, let's suppose you are holding your phone (which we also suppose that already includes an IMU) with the screen pointing up, and you define a vector normal to the screen as a *forward direction* (this would be the so-called *body frame*). Then, if you move the phone in that direction, the IMU could measure an acceleration *forward*. However you, as an external observer, would observe that the phone moved *upward* rather than *forward*, because the notion of *forward* is different from your perspective.
That apparent inconsistency is caused by the different coordinate frames we define and is fixed by knowing the relative transformation between them; in this case, that transformation is the rotation matrix we were talking before.